# How to set Lion's Finder to "Show All" by default instead of "Show Less"

Tags: osx-lion, finder

"Show Less" requiring horizontal scrolling is the worst.

Anyone out there know of a terminal command or something to kill this "feature"? I would like my files to "Show All" by default ALWAYS when sorting by type or label or what have you.

Comment: Just use list view instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any way to make it the default, but you can still use the old sorting modes without all the sections. If you hold option, the View > Arrange By menu turns into Sort By.

[image]

Note that the Arrange By mode has to be set to none by pressing ⌃⌘0 first.